# Display YAML and chunks without executing them in blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

In an article made with `blogdown`, I would like to show the YAML and some chunks I used in a previous work. Therefore, I would like to display them without executing them, just as-is. I tried to embed the YAML and the chunks with 4 backticks but the execution of chunks still depends on their options. Here's an example:

`````
---
title: ""
author: ''
date: ""
output:
  blogdown::html_page
---
  
Display a fake YAML and a fake chunk:
````
---
title: ""
author: ''
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document
---
```{r}
1 + 1
```
````
`````

As you can see, the chunk containing `1+1` is executed. This is what should be displayed:

````
---
title: ""
author: ''
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document
---
```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

How can I do that? If it matters, the extension of my file is `.Rmarkdown`, and not `.Rmd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look in the [source](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-book/blob/master/02-basics.Rmd) of the RMarkdown book. Besides the four backticks the trick is to put

```
`r ''`
```

in front of the code chunk. Try this:

`````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

````markdown
---
title: ""
author: ''
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document
---
`r ''````{r}
1 + 1
```
````
`````